# Searching for words in a CSV file column with str.contains

Tags: python, pandas, string, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
start_date,end_date,pollster,sponsor,sample_size,population,party,subject,tracking,text,approve,disapprove,url
    2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,1500,a,all,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,42,29,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
    2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,376,a,R,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,75,6,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
    2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,523,a,D,Trump,TRUE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,21,51,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
    2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,599,a,I,Trump,,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,39,25,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
    2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,"",2200,a,all,Trump,TURE,Do you approve or disapprove of the job each of the following is doing in handling the spread of coronavirus in the United States? President Donald Trump,57,22,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
```

**And I want to find all the rows where the column "text" contains both the word "Trump" and "coronavirus"**

I am using str.contains()

```
approval_polls[approval_polls.text.str.contains("Trump", "coronavirus")]
```

**It seems as I was getting the correct output, but i am not sure if str.contains() can take two words as parameters.**

Can anyone help me with that?

Output:

```
start_date  end_date    pollster    sponsor     sample_size     population  party   subject     tracking    text    approve     disapprove  url
0   2020-02-02  2020-02-04  YouGov  Economist   1500.0  a   all     Trump   FALSE   Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s...   42.0    29.0    https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_...
1   2020-02-02  2020-02-04  YouGov  Economist   376.0   a   R   Trump   FALSE   Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s...   75.0    6.0     https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_...
2   2020-02-02  2020-02-04  YouGov  Economist   523.0   a   D   Trump   FALSE   Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s...   21.0    51.0    https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_...
```

Comment: try to put `contains("anydata", "Trump")` (i.e at 2nd position)and hopefully you will see unexpected result. then try `contains("anydata | Trump")` or operator . pls refer [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Answer (score 2):

In your example case all rows contain both keywords, so you should get all five rows returned.

With the function call `contains('Trump', 'coronavirus')` you get all rows that have 'Trump' OR 'coronavirus' in its text column. To get only columns that contain 'Trump' AND 'coronavirus' you can use the following

```
df[df['text'].str.contains('Trump') & df['text'].str.contains('coronavirus')]
```

Or you could use a regular expression, e.g.,

```
df[df['text'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*Trump)(?=.*coronavirus)')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to do this, but in a somewhat crafted way since we don't have a direct representative of the "AND" operator in regex.

```
import re

approval_polls[approval_polls.text.str.contains('(?=.*trump)(?=.*coronavirus)', regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```